# A MYSQL Function Return records based on consecutive value of column

Tags: mysql, sql

How to write a MYSQL function to return records based on consecutive value of a column(int or date or timestamp).

For example ：

// id consecutive 4 times record ，id : 5,6,7,8

```
select * from employee where consecutive(id,4);
```

// date consecutive 4 dates record

```
select * from employee where consecutive(date,4);
```

//as long as id is consecutive, return all.

```
select * from employee where consecutive (date，null);
```

Comment: You cannot.  `where` operates on a single row at a time.  You are looking for a function in the `where` clause that operates on multiple rows.

Comment: You should also give us the query you used to generate a particular order for the `id` column.  Consecutive values only has a meaning with regard to a certain order in your records.

Comment: Your question is unclear if the 4 `employee.id` values `5,6,7,8` are because there are 4 values in the database starting at `5`, or because you want all values `> 4` and they only go up to 8, or some other reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ISO-standard SQL 2003 or later I'd use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY id )` combined with `OFFSET`. This query works in SQL Server 2012 or later, Oracle 10g or later, PostgreSQL, or [MySQL 8 or later](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html) - but hardly anyone runs MySQL 8...

For your first example:

```
SELECT
    employee.*
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            id,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY id ) AS rn
        FROM
            employee
    ) AS sq

    INNER JOIN employee ON employee.id = sq.id
ORDER BY
    id
OFFSET
    0 ROWS FETCH 4
```

Fortunately MySQL lets you increment variables and evaluate other *impure* expressions in a `SELECT` as though they're evaluated iteratively (this is an incorrect assumption to make in the "SQL way of thinking").

[So here's a trick to get a row-rank in MySQL, using an inline initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3333697/159145):

```
SELECT
    *,
    @rank := @rank + 1 AS rn
FROM
    employee,
    ( SELECT @rank := 0 )
ORDER BY
    employee.id
```

So we can use this as our subquery:

```
SELECT
    employee.*
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            employee.id,
            @rank := @rank + 1 AS rn
        FROM
            employee,
            ( SELECT @rank := 0 )
        ORDER BY
            employee.id
    ) AS sq

    INNER JOIN employee ON employee.id = sq.id

ORDER BY
    id
LIMIT
    4 OFFSET 0
```